# Flutter how to Copy PDF to Downloads Folder on Android Device

Tags: flutter, dart, path

I generate pdf file in flutter app.
I am trying to copy the pdf to the Download directory of the android device.
Looking at the `path_provider` package, I get the path to a directory that can only be accessed within the app.

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
```

Do you know how to copy my pdf to a download folder that is not accessible from within the app but can be accessed by users?

Comment: Android don't recommend this anymore. If you do so. Android Google Play will block your app and will not publish it. Somehow if you managed to download the file into the download folder you have to ask for exception from Google Play to let your app publish. In this case you have to provide proper reason why do you want to save your file into the download directory.

Comment: Thanks for the good info, I guess I'll have to find another way

Answer (score 0):

Use  [downloads_path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider), on android it will save the file on Downloads

Comment: This is a very outdated package. It is not compatible with current Android devices and SDKs.